# How to convert detectMSERFeatures function in MATLAB to C?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, matlab-coder

I have written a computer vision code which uses MSER to detect features in MATLAB. I used the built in 'detectMSERFeatures' function to process a locally saved video. Now, I  want to port it t C language using MATLAB Coder. But, MATLAB Coder doesn't support this function. I've attached a screenshot of the output. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brYQT.png]

My code is as follows:

```
function count = master
% Clear workspace and Initialize Frame count
clear all;
F=0;
count=0;
% 1.Input Video Object Handler Definition
inputVideo = vision.VideoFileReader('video.mp4');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

% 2.Cropping Height and Width of frame. Subject to convenient
%   adjustments according to the position of camera. Mainly using to
%   crop out street lights from the top of the frame.
height = floor(inputVideo.info().VideoSize(2)*0.7);
width = inputVideo.info().VideoSize(1);
crop = vision.ImagePadder(...
                        'SizeMethod','Output size', ...
                        'NumOutputRowsSource','Property', ...
                        'RowPaddingLocation','Top', ...
                        'NumOutputRows', height, ...
                        'NumOutputColumns', width);

% 3.Frame Conversion from True Colour to Grayscale
gray = vision.ColorSpaceConverter;
gray.Conversion = 'RGB to intensity';

% 4.Implementation on individual frames till the end of video.
while(~isDone(inputVideo))
% Current Frame number
F = F + 1;
%flag=0
% Current Frame
currentFrame = step(inputVideo);
% Crop
currentFrame = step(crop, currentFrame);
% Convert to Grayscale
currentFrame = step(gray, currentFrame);
% Threshold
currentFrame(currentFrame<0.7843) = 0;
% Detect MSER Regions
regions = detectMSERFeatures(currentFrame, ...
                            'RegionAreaRange', [800 3000], ...
                            'ThresholdDelta', 4);
% Check for 'big bright blob(s)', or high incoming beam
% and output detected blob count and corresponding frame
if(regions.Count >= 2 && regions.Count <=6)
    disp([regions.Count, F]);
    %flag=1;
    count= count+1;

end
% Port frame to player
step(videoPlayer,currentFrame);
end

%5.Release both player and video file instances
release(inputVideo);
release(videoPlayer);
```

I'm using MATLAB R2013a.

Comment: Docs says it supports code generation using a "platform specific precompiled library". What is your problem? some error? whichone?

Comment: "For code generation, the function outputs regions.PixelList as an array. The region sizes are defined in regions.Lengths."

Comment: Can you post code? As @Ander points out, it is supported by Coder, but with some limitations.  Also, what version of Matlab are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this would be to upgrade to a more recent version of MATLAB. Code generation support for `detectMSERFeatures` was added in R2013b release.